# bash script - Add string to cell in html table IF title of row is already in

Tags: shell-script, html

I have a bash script that checks on the status of certain processes and aspects of multiple servers and i am pushing the results to an html file to display in an email.

Some servers have as many as 6 checks and others only 3. Currently my html table lists the server hostname in the left column and depending on the result of the check will display a message for that server and the check in the right column. This means in the left column i can have the same server name multiple times.

How can i add the server name once to the left column and in the right column but all the checks in the same row?

Comment: don't output each server's status results as you get them. store them in an associative array (with key = hostname) and print them in a loop later.   also, consider writing your script in perl - it excels at this kind of thing.  sh excels at controlling the execution of other programs, not summarising data or creating reports.

Comment: if i user an associative array with the host names as keys how do i add multiple values to the key?

Comment: in perl, you'd use a Hash of Arrays (HoA).  In bash, use two associative arrays.  or maybe store comma- or other delimiter- separated values (but splitting and joining is a pain in bash).